# How to find sterile node in parent/child relationship table?

Tags: mysql, row, parent, relationship

If I have a simple table that is marked by some `GUID` like so (just assume it only has these two columns):

`GUID` | `parentGUID`

how do I find a sterile node (or row) such that no children have their `parentGUID` as its `GUID`. Assume that "no children" are just marked as empty.

This was my original attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM dagr d1, dagr d2
WHERE d1.parentGUID = ''
AND d2.parentGUID != ''
AND d1.guid != d2.parentGUID
AND d1.guid != d2.guid
```

My thought process: Compare the list of orphans (i.e. Rows with no parent) with that non-orphans (i.e. Rows that have a parent). But honestly that probably makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell if this is what you're asking for, but if you want to find a row in dagr with no matching rows, you could try a LEFT JOIN. It's probably a little late for your purposes but the googlers may find some use of this.

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM dagr d1
LEFT JOIN dagr d2
ON d1.guid = d2.parentGUIDIS 
WHERE d2.parentGUIDIS NULL
```

See LEFT JOIN http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php